# Create a new line after a limited width

Tags: java

Hi I've been head banging on this simple method.

**The goal:** is to create a new line after the width provided. E.g. if the width is 20 that means after 15 chars create a new line. Although there is Wordwrap.Utils to achieve this. I wanted to do this manually.

**The Problem:** is that the output is working however, if a word in the sentence exceeds the 15 characters it is chopped off and a new line is created. E.G. 
`Hi my name is J
immy and I love
 programming.`

As you can see the word 'Jimmy' is chopped off.

**The Question:** is how can I ensure that if a word makes the sentence more than 15 characters, create a new line before the word rather than chopping it of? So the output becomes:

`Hi my name is
Jimmy and I
love
programming.`

The Class is Below:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){

    String txt = "Hi my name is Jimmy and I love programming.";
    int width = 15;

    System.out.println(lineLength(txt, width));

}

public static String lineLength(String str, int width) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(true) {
        if(str.length() <= width) {
            sb.append(str);
            break;
        }

        sb.append(str.substring(0, width));
        sb.append("\n");
        str = str.substring(width);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Use String.split(" ") to separate words and then check how many of these words you can fit on a line.

Comment: Or do something like string. if (!charAt(width).equals(" "){width -1} afterwards reset your with: with = 15; wrap this up in a while-loop and it should work

Comment: @Arty My Question is, what if the first word is already more than 15 characters long? What should the output be?

Comment: @user3437460 then that word can exceptionally be split at the nth character(15th character). But that will be another check as I would have to first check if a word is longer than the width. And if so then chop the word at the 15 character. In the case of this question I'm asking assuming that the text does not contain words longer than the width itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *issue* with your code is that you are not keeping track of word breaks. Making a slight change to your program, wherein it will look for the closest white space such that the position of the white space is not beyond the length of the word you are after.

```
    public static String lineLength(String str, int width) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();       

    while (true) {
        if (str.length() <= width) {
            sb.append(str);
            break;
        }

        int cutOff = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        while(((temp = str.indexOf(" ", ++temp)) < width) && (temp >= 0))
        {
            cutOff = temp;
        }

        //Extra check in case the word itself is longer than the wrap
        if(cutOff == 0)
        {
            sb.append(str);
            return sb.toString();
        }   
        String newString = str.substring(0, cutOff);           

        sb.append(newString);
        sb.append("\n");
        str = str.substring(cutOff);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

**Output:**

```
Hi my name is
 Jimmy and I
 love
 programming.
```

You can still use Stringbuilder on the following codes.

```
String str = "Hi my name is Jimmy and I love programming.";
String txt = "";
int len = 15;               

while(str.length() > 0){
        if(str.length() < len){
            txt += str;
            str = "";
        }           
        else if(str.charAt(len) == ' '){
            txt += str.substring(0, len+1) + "\n";
            str = str.substring(len+1);
        }                   
        else{
            txt += str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(' ', len)) + "\n";
            str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(' ', len));
        }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm should search for the last word delimiter ( space, dot, comma etc) in the next 16 characters of the string. If such a character does not exist ( the next word has more than 15 characters) then split the word at the 15th character.

Comment: You can also add rules and preferences like: split the last word of the sentence so that you do not end up creating a 3 character sentence. 


Example: 
- alpha betagamma : split the last word
- alpha beta gamma: split before gamma